# Grouping date without time using prisma - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm working on an application using Next.js, Prisma, and MongoDB. In my project, I have a log (which has date) collection, and I'd like to group the records by date while excluding the time part, focusing only on the year, month, and day.

Here's the code example:

```
 const logs = await db.log.groupBy({
        by: ["date"],
          _sum: {
          count: true,
        },
        orderBy: {
          date: "asc",
        },
        ....
        .....
        .......
```

The issue I'm facing is that the grouping includes the time part, whereas I want to group by date only. Is there a way to achieve this directly using Prisma, or should I consider using a different approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I researched, there is no way to separate DateTime using Prisma API. For this reason, I solved my problem by using aggregateRaw.

Comment: You can add this kind of answer as a comment to the solution not as a answer.